# Django on Debian 9 - ImportError: No module named 'PROJECT.settings.py'

Tags: python, django, debian, django-migrations

I'm trying to deploy my Django app on Google compute engine Debian VM instance, I have installed the Python(3.6) and setup virtual environment then clone my Django application which is working perfectly well on the local system.
When I try to run `python manage.py migrate` command it returns an error as:

> ImportError: No module named 'Fetchors.settings.py'; 'Fetchors.settings' is not a package

**Here's my `Fetchors/wsgi.py`:**

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
print(path)
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Fetchors.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

> Update: my directory struture is:

```
|-Fetchors
  |--Fetchors
   |--settings.py
  |--manage.py
```

**here's my `manage.py`:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Fetchors.settings.py")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError:
        # The above import may fail for some other reason. Ensure that the
        # issue is really that Django is missing to avoid masking other
        # exceptions on Python 2.
        try:
            import django
        except ImportError:
            raise ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            )
        raise
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

What can be wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your `Fetchors` have a `settings.py` file?

Comment: Yes, it has, Project name is `Fetchors` then the main app name is also `Fetchors` .So, I have `Fetchors/Fetchors/settings.py`

Comment: Have you added the line `Fetchors.settings.py` somewhere?

Comment: it's only mentioned as `Fetchors.settings` in `wsgi.py`

Answer (score 0):

Add `__init__.py` file in your innermost Fetchors folder if it's not available.
So your directory structure should look like below:

```
|-Fetchors
  |--Fetchors
   |--__init__.py
   |--settings.py
  |--manage.py
```

This lets the python know to treat the Fetchors is a package. `__init__.py` can be empty file. And it should be already present in the folder.

Comment: Can you post the output for the path variable being set in wsgi.py? Most probably that will cause the issue if the project folder is not part of path.